# Problem with String::replaceFirst() when used with "*"?

Tags: java, string

```
private String unusedDigits = new String("0123456789*#");
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst("1", "");
//...
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst("*", ""); // <--- problem
```

Am a Java beginner. Why am I facing problem when using `replaceFirst()` with `"*"` ? It goes to some different code flow (which is related to some `synchronized`). If I comment that statement then things work fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `replaceFirst()`, The first parameter is a regex. You can use `Pattern.quote("*")` instead:

```
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("*"), "");
```

Comment: thanks. actually "*" is a variable (I used string literal for simplicity) and this answer suits best

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the * character, as it is a special regex character:

```
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst("\\*", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

replaceFirst requires regular expression as an argument. '*' is a special character in regex so you should use

```
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst("\\*", "");
```

to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceFirst` takes a regular expression as it's first argument.  Since `*` is a special character you need to escape it.

Try this:

```
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst("\\*", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

replaceFirst argument is a regex, and * has a specific meaning in regex, so to escape the regex part change to

```
unusedDigits = unusedDigits.replaceFirst("\\*", "");
```

Comment: (This is my Code) String x ="${data} m,.m,.m,";
String y = x.replaceFirst("${data}", "Amaan");
System.out.println(y);

Comment: hey i got solution by akhatra..String x ="${data} m,.m,.m,";
  String y = x.replaceFirst("\\$\\{data\\}", "Amaan");
  System.out.println(y);